# Add 2 I2c devices with the same adress in dts

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, device-tree

I have a 2 different board each with a I2c device, the devices have the same address. I want to build one firmware where I can control both of devices depends on which device is connected to the I2C bus

```
device1@30 {
        compatible = "device1";
        reg = <0x30>;
        clock-mode = /bits/ 8 <1>;
        ....
device2@30 {
        compatible = "device2";
        reg = <0x30>;
        clock-mode = /bits/ 8 <1>;
```

I got an error when trying to read from the register of the second device which says that device 2 that be binded. How can I resolve this problem  ?

NB : I have only 1 I2C Bus

I tried to add some detection function in the first and second device ( read ID register ) but it fails because I can't read the reg of the second device.

Comment: your DTS needs to have one or the other. In fact, part of the reason DTS exists, is so that each board can have its own DTS depending on what is on that board.

Comment: it is the same board. but for each board I have different device

Comment: and the DTS should tell Linux which device you have.

Comment: How do "same board" and "each board" go together? Do you mean "similar boards" instead of "same"?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes similar boards but 2 different devices with same functionalities, the problem is they have the same addresses

Comment: They can be the same board with both devices in DTS if they have different addresses. With the same address, they are different boards, so must have different DTS.